# Rabin-Karp String matching

Tags: java, algorithm, strings, search

I am learning algorithms and have implemented the [Rabin-Karp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) string search algorithm.   I didn't implement a rolling `HashCode`, but it's judged correct by [this online judge](https://leetcode.com/problems/implement-strstr).

It's slower than the `str.indexOf()` implementation (7ms, compared to 4 ms). Can this be improved? What is the time complexity for this?

```
class Solution {
public int strStr(String haystack, String needle) {
    if (haystack == null || needle == null)
        return -1;
    int needleHash = hashCode(needle);
    int plen = needle.length();
    boolean t = true;
    int tlen = haystack.length() - needle.length() + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < tlen; i++) {
        String sub = haystack.substring(i, plen + i);
        int haystackHash = hashCode(sub);
        if (haystackHash == needleHash) {
            for (int j = 0; j < plen; j++) {
                char[] charN = needle.toCharArray();
                char[] charH = sub.toCharArray();
                if (charN[j] != charH[j]) {
                    t = false;
                }
            }
            if (t == true) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public int hashCode(String value) {
    int h = 777;
    if (value.length() > 0) {
        char val[] = value.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
            h = 31 * h + val[i];
        }
    }
    return h;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have some tests that show it produces correct results?  It would be useful to include them with the code, for the benefit of reviewers.

Comment: Code Review is for code which works as intended, **to the best of the author's knowledge**. We are not a code-testing facility. You'll have to put some effort in yourself. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @Mast Toby it got selected as an answer passing all the test cases in online judge. I want if anyone could tell thats the correct implementation of the algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the essential benefit of using a rolling hash:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tlen; i++) {
    String sub = haystack.substring(i, plen + i);
    int haystackHash = hashCode(sub);
```

Here, we examine **`plen`** characters of `haystack` at every character position, which is O(*mn*) where `m` is the haystack length and `n` the needle length.

By using a rolling hash, we only need to examine **two** characters each time around the loop (one to add to the hash, and one to remove from it).  That is of course O(*m*), which greatly improves the efficiency when `n` is large.

Only inspect the substring when there's a hash match, which should be infrequent.

---

Other issues:

- Why convert `needle` and `sub` to char arrays to compare them?  You certainly don't want to do that every time around the `j` loop; you don't even need that loop if you write `if (sub == needle) return i;`.
- `if (t == true)` is more simply written `if (t)` since that's the only true value that `t` can hold.  Again, not needed when you eliminate the `j` loop.

---

## Improved code

You meant to write something more like this:

```
public int strStr(final String haystack, final String needle)
{
    if (haystack == null || needle == null)
        return -1;

    final int nlen = needle.length();
    final int hlen = haystack.length();
    if (nlen > hlen)
        return -1;

    int needleHash = 0;
    int hash_remove = 1;
    for (char c: needle.toCharArray()) {
        needleHash = addHash(needleHash, c);
        hash_remove = addHash(hash_remove, '\0');
    }

    int haystackHash = 0;
    for (int i = 0;  i < nlen - 1;  ++i) {
        haystackHash = addHash(haystackHash, haystack.charAt(i));
    }

    for (int i = 0;  i + nlen < hlen;  ++i) {
        haystackHash = addHash(haystackHash, haystack.charAt(i + nlen));
        if (haystackHash == needleHash && haystack.substring(i, i+nlen) == needle)
            return i;
        haystackHash -= haystack.charAt(i) * hash_remove;
    }

    return -1;
}

private int addHash(int h, char c)
{
    // calculation may overflow, but that's fine
    return 31 * h + c;
}
```

The only magic in there is the computation and use of `hash_remove`, to undo the effect of characters that have moved out of the match window.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work as OP wanted, please try `"hello"
"ll"` for the input.

Comment: I just wrote "something like" - I never claimed it was correct!  :-p

Comment: Hahah, yeah... sorry I missed it out